# I get the error which i cant fix : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, bad-alloc

I used 2D dynamic array and I dont know how to fix the error, please help me! I wanna get a string from user and separate it to some string and put them into the 2d dynamic array.
its the part of code where I allocate the array.

```
    int colCount,rowCount;
    string** table = new string*[rowCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    {
    table[i] = new string[colCount];
    }
```

Comment: To begin with you should probably use `std::vector` instead. You *can* nest a vector inside another vector.

Comment: As for your problem, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. For example you need to tell us the values of `colCount` and `rowCount`, and preferably show us how you initialize them. And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not initialize `colCount` and `rowCount`, thus their values are garbage. You try to dynamically allocate memory with uninitialized variables, which, of course, invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Initialize your variables, like:

```
int colCount = 5, rowCount = 5;
```

---

PS: Since this is C++, I suggest you use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) as a 2D array, like this for example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> table;
```

Comment: I want the type to be string , can I use a 2D vector of strings for simulating a kind database?

Comment: A 2D vectror gives you a matrix @shirazy, where `table[i][j]` is a string. So yes!

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. I want to have a 2D vector of strings, is that possible ? something like this vector < vector <string> > or using a 2D dynamic array would be a better idea?

Comment: @shirazy yes, sorry! Check my update answer, and accept it if it helped! =)